# Prove that $|Y| = |\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}|$, where $Y$ is the set of all non-injective functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $Y$ be the set of all non injective functions from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, i.e., for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the cardinality $\bigl| f^{-1}({n}) \bigr|$ is different from $1$. I need to prove this cardinality equivalence.

So to do that I need to find an injective function from $Y$ to $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and another one from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ to $Y$.

The first one is obvious because $Y \subseteq (\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N})$.

I'm having trouble finding the second one. I tried with mod, but it makes it non-injective. Another example?

Comment: Please use Mathjax. What is $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ again, please. This appears written rather hastefully. Keep in mind that your question on MSE is not just for you. It is also for whomever reads this and is interested, and so it has to be understandable to the general audience here, and not just to whoever answered your question.

Comment: I think your description that $|f^{-1}(n)|\neq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not accurately describing non-injective functions. Why should this be required to hold for all $n$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** To each function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ correspond a new function $F:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by $F(2n)=f(n)$ and $F(2n+1)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any non-injective surjection $h:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$

(e.g., with the convention $\min(\Bbb N)=0$: $h(0)=0$ and $\forall n\ge1\quad h(n)=n-1$). Then,

$$f\mapsto f\circ h$$ is an injection from $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ into $Y$.